# Access open form doesn't understand imported field

Tags: ms-access, vba

I use the following code to open the form on a specific record or in add data mode:

```
Private Sub Open_Click()

    Dim recordID As Integer

    recordID = Me.ID
    'Debug.Print Me.ID
    'Stop
    If Me.ID <> "" Then
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Add Task", acNormal, , "ID=" & recordID, acFormEdit
    Else
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Add Task", acNormal, , , acFormAdd
    End If

End Sub
```

Even though Access understands and prints my ID, it then fails to open the form at that record. This happens only when I add records by importing them from Excel.

Could you please help?

Answer (score 0):

`Me.ID` is an integer, and you compare it to a string. This triggers a type mismatch runtime error with `Option Explicit` on, but just returns `Null` with `Option Explicit` off, which is seen as `False` in your `If` statement.

Please add `Option Explicit`, and respect data types (learn about Option Explicit [here](http://www.vbforums.com/showthread.php?461140-Classic-VB-What-is-Option-Explicit-and-why-should-I-use-it).

The proper code:

```
Private Sub Open_Click() 

    Dim recordID As Integer

    If Not IsNull(Me.ID) Then 
        'Note that IsNull(RecordID) would always return true, as integers can't be Null.
        recordID = Me.ID 
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Add Task", acNormal, , "ID=" & recordID, acFormEdit 
    Else 
        DoCmd.OpenForm "Add Task", acNormal, , , acFormAdd 
    End If 

End Sub
```